# Как перемешать такой массив рандомно?

Tags: javascript

```js
let array = [
  ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'],
  ['test11', 'test22', 'test33', 'test44'],
  ['test111', 'test222', 'test333', 'test444'],
];

function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)) - 0.5;
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
  return array
}

console.log(shuffle(array[0]))
```

на выходе просто меняет местами [ 'test4', 'test3', 'test2', 'test1' ]
как сделать что бы рандомно перемешалось, пример ('test4','test1','test3','test2')

Comment: ты уверен, что твой код _на выходе просто меняет местами_?

Comment: и откуда вы взяли 0.5 в этом коде: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12646864/9033215